# Is there a viable alternative for the (defunct) FileSystem API for Web Apps?

Tags: android, html, cordova, web-applications, html5-filesystem

Whilst I could potentially have my web app only available as a Chrome App, or as a web app with minimal browser support, is there any viable alternative for the FileSystem API?

Ideally I'm looking for a cross-platform solution that will allow me to storage images along with some basic HTML and JS files on the users device, whether its a PC browser, or a Tablet for example.

I think Cordova has File support, but only up to version 3.3.0 (although there seems to be a File plugin available, but I'm not sure what version it is for). Would this be classed as viable/some-what future-proof?

Comment: Cordova's File API mimics the html5 API. The API is still there, but recently they took it out of the core plugins and it is now available as an [optional plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

Comment: Will the Cordova Plugin work when used by a browser that doesn't support the FileSystem API? E.g IE and Firefox do not support it, according to www.caniuse.com

Comment: No, Cordova works almost only with mobile OSes. There's Windows 8 support, but you need to package your web app as a windows app.

Comment: Hmm, https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file states it works for browsers? But is that only browsers like Chrome, that support the API?

Comment: I dont' know what do they mean. The last version of Cordova I used wont fire the `onDeviceReady` callback unless it was being run in a supported platform. Trying to load Cordova in a regular browser jproduced errors. Maybe its different now?